# Opening any 2mb jpg image in dired freezes emacs

Tags: dired, images, exwm

Viewing any .jpg image > 1MB makes emacs unresponsive for over a minute. <200KB .jpg work instantly. Any ideas where to start investigating?

Hitting `RET` on this [2.8MB](https://picjumbo.com/wp-content/uploads/kitten-free-photo.jpg).jpg. Profiler (cpu+mem) report:

```
    292,936,569  76% - command-execute
    292,936,569  76%  - call-interactively
    292,936,569  76%   - funcall-interactively
    292,098,498  76%    - dired-find-file
    292,096,450  76%     - dired--find-possibly-alternative-file
    292,096,450  76%      - dired--find-file
    292,096,450  76%       - find-file
    292,073,234  76%        - find-file-noselect
    292,073,234  76%         - apply
    292,073,234  76%          - editorconfig--advice-find-file-noselect
    292,059,882  76%           - apply
    292,059,882  76%            - #<compiled -0xaf78a151e9b2f04>
```

A repeating term while *suffering* :) this problem, seems `page-break-lines`.
E.g. hitting a couple of keys while listening to the screaming cpu fan goes raises:
`Error during redisplay: (page-break-lines--update-display-tables #<frame emacs@x 0x5be5fbf7cba0>) signaled (quit) [2 times]`

Profiler report (created between opening an image and `evil-window-left)`

```
43163  83% - ...
40636  78%  - page-break-lines--update-display-tables
40636  78%   - if
40636  78%    - mapc
40636  78%     - page-break-lines--update-display-table
40636  78%      - save-current-buffer
40636  78%       - let
40636  78%        - save-current-buffer
40636  78%         - unwind-protect
21502  41%          + progn
19134  36%          - internal--after-with-selected-window
19134  36%           - select-window
19134  36%            - apply
19134  36%             - ad-Advice-select-window
19134  36%              - evil-refresh-cursor
19134  36%               - evil-set-cursor
19134  36%                - evil-set-cursor-color
19134  36%                   set-cursor-color
 2449   4%  + which-key--hide-popup
   75   0%    Automatic GC
    3   0%  + exwm-layout--refresh
 4804   9% + redisplay_internal (C function)
 3733   7% + command-execute
  226   0% + timer-event-handler
    2   0% + direnv--maybe-update-environment
```

I toggled `global-page-break-lines-mode` to disable the mode, yet the the issue **and** it's appearing in profiler remains.

Environment:

```
- OS: gnu/linux
- Emacs: 29.2
- Spacemacs: 0.999.0
- Spacemacs branch: develop (rev. ca10effc9)
- Graphic display: t
- Running in daemon: t
- Distribution: spacemacs
- Editing style: vim
- Completion: helm
```

`C-h v system-configuration-options`

```
"--sysconfdir=/etc --prefix=/usr --libexecdir=/usr/lib --with-tree-sitter --localstatedir=/var --with-cairo --disable-build-details --with-harfbuzz --with-libsystemd --with-modules --with-x-toolkit=gtk3 'CFLAGS=-march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions         -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security         -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/emacs/src=/usr/src/debug/emacs -flto=auto' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -flto=auto'"
```

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: If the problem persists even with emacs -Q, run a [profile](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Profiling.html): M-x profiler-start RET cpu+mem RET, open the image and then do M-x profiler-report and eyeball the reports to see if something looks funky. Do the same thing for a small image, just so that you can see if there are glaring differences in the profiler reports.